# R recompile packages failing because failing

Tags: r, rcpp

On my linux cluster, I am having trouble recompiling R packages that need to be recompiled
 with the removal of `libRcpp.so` in the latest release.  The end goal is
 to get the R package DEseq2 running. We have installed a new version
 of g++ in `/opt/bin` directory have new libraries in `/opt/lib64`. I have
 also created `.R/Makevars` that has these directives:

```
CXX=/opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64

 -Wl,-llibstdc++ CC=/opt/bin/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-llibstdc++ 
SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS= -fopenmp
```

---

"Various versions of Makevars fail, this is just my latest attempt to
 overcome a loader problem of it not finding libstdc++ when it links
 armadillo.  As you can see, it is looking in `/usr/lib64` instead of
 `/opt/lib64`. It is as if my `-Wl` directives are ignored. I am
 running R as sudo.

Also my .bashrc has:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib64:/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/lib:~/perl/lib:~/lib/bamtools

LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/lib64:$LD_RUN_PATH:~/lib

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export LD_RUN_PATH
```

---

Here is what I get when I try to compile in R the new packages needing
 recompilation:

---

```
    install.packages(onCRAN, lib=lib, repos=rep)
     trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.4.000.2.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 892941 bytes (872 Kb)
     opened URL
     ==================================================
     downloaded 872 Kb

     * installing *source* package âRcppArmadilloâ ...
     ** package âRcppArmadilloâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
     * checking LAPACK_LIBS divide-and-conquer complex SVD unavailable via R-supplied LAPACK
     * divide-and-conquer algorithm for complex SVD will be redirected to default
     ** libs
     /opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-llibstdc++ -I/opt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
     /opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-llibstdc++ -I/opt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
     /opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-llibstdc++ -I/opt/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
     Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
       unable to load shared object '/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
     Calls: ::: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
     Execution halted
     /opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-llibstdc++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/opt/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack
 -L/opt/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm
     Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
       unable to load shared object '/opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by        /opt/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)`
     Calls: ::: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
     Execution halted
     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibstdc++
     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
     ERROR: compilation failed for package âRcppArmadilloâ
     * removing â/opt/lib64/RcppArmadilloâ
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
 /tmp/RtmpZty35f/downloaded_packages
```

Warning message:

```
In install.packages(onCRAN, lib = lib, repos = rep) :
   installation of package RcppArmadillo had non-zero exit code
```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick comments:

1. The definition of `CXX` in `CXX=/opt/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib64 -Wl,-L,/opt/lib64` is a little, ahem, unusual as it mixes linker instructions (for the `ld` binary). I would try again without.
2. The errors in compiling RcppArmadillo make little sense, it should try to load `libRcpp.so`. And `'GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found` suggests that you may have a path setup.

I would try a simpler setup, fewer bells and whistles, and then work from the inside out: Rebuild / reinstall Rcpp, then RcppArmadillo and so on.  It works for a lot of people using more standard setups.