# Customize where R looks for shared objects?

Tags: r, g++, rcpp, centos5, g++4.8

This question is similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597018/r-recompile-packages-failing-because-failing) with respect to RcppArmadillo.

Some quick context:

I currently must work on a CentOS 5 system.  Naturally, the compiler that comes with CentOS 5 was too old so we installed gcc-4.8.3.  Now, others were concerned about back compatibility with the old compiler so the new gcc was placed in the `opt` directory.  In order to use the upgraded g++ I must set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in R with `Sys.setenv`

```
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib:/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64")
```

Now, I also need to install an archived version of RcppArmadillo.  I get the archived package from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RcppArmadillo/) and install with:

```
install.packages("RcppArmadillo_0.3.930.1.tar.gz", repose=NULL, type="source")
```

This appears to work without issue but when I try to load the library I get the following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so)
```

From what think I understand is that the `libstdc++.so` file that is found is too old, i.e. not the newer one that is in the `opt` directory.  I thought this would have been solved by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` above but it seems to still be looking in `/usr/lib64/`.  Is there any way for me to have R look in this other directory to get the appropriate `so` file?  Naturally if I have done something strange that would have caused this I am open to other solutions (besides overwriting the old gcc version).

**EDIT**

I have also noticed that upon installation the `-shared` is again showing the `usr/` path as opposed to the `opt/` path.  This is what I want to update so R will also search the `opt` directory.

```
* installing *source* package âRcppArmadilloâ ...
** package âRcppArmadilloâ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* checking LAPACK_LIBS divide-and-conquer complex SVD unavailable via R-supplied LAPACK
* divide-and-conquer algorithm for complex SVD will be redirected to default
** libs
g++ -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-variadic-macros -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-variadic-macros -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-variadic-macros -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/usr/bin/gfortran -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

**UPDATE**

I have also tried manually appending the `opt` directory by creating a `Makevars` file in the `.R` directory by setting `PKG_LIBS += -L$(OPT_PATH)`, where `OPT_PATH = /opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64`.  The `shared` line during compilation looks like this:

```
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -L/usr/bin/gfortran -L/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

But I still get the same error:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
```

Even stranger (at least to me) is that running `ldd` shows that the `RcppArmadillo.so` file is pointing to the correct file.

```
ldd /usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so
...
libstdc++.so.6 => /opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002ae950a3d000)
...
```

which does contain `GLIBCXX_3.4.9`

Comment: I'd blame your machine or setup. I have never had such issues on Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I do blame it, have been trying to get them to upgrade for months.  But stuck right now trying to find a workaround instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually came to a solution with the current system.  I needed to coordinate with our IT department to get temporary sudo privileges.  Then, after switching to root I needed to export the following two environmental variables.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib:/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64
export LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib:/opt/gcc-4.8.3/rtf/lib64
```

Then, while still as root, I opened R and ran

```
install.packages('RcppArmadillo')
```

This installed the latest RcppArmadillo package on our CentOS 5.8 system with our gcc-4.8.3 compiler in its non-standard location in `opt`.  I verified the installation worked by switching to a normal user and loading the package successfully.